Implementing infinite scroll in React Native
I've seen some solutions for this online, but I can't get any of them to work.
I have a React Native app which loads data from an API.  The data is paginated; each time I retrieve a page, I receive the results for that page, plus the url for the next page.  So a typical response from the API is in this format (obviously it's a bit more complex than this, but this is the gist):
{
  data: [
    { key: xx, title: 'Item 1' },
    { key: yy, title: 'Item 2' }
  ], 
  next: 'www/url/to/next/page/of/results'
}

I want to display each item on screen, and when the user scrolls to the bottom of the screen, the next set of results should load.  I'm trying to use a FlatList for this.
So far I have (I don't have any kind of error checking or anything in yet; just trying to get it to work first):
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [next, setNext] = React.useState<string>(BASE_URL); // URL of first page of results
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(true);
  const [displayItems, setDisplayItems] = React.useState<Item[]|null>(null);

  // Get next page of items
  const fetchItems = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await client(next, 'GET'); // Just calls axios
    setDisplayItems((items) => items.concat(response.data));
    setNext(response.next);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  // Get items on first loading screen
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, [fetchItems]);

  // Show items
  if (isLoading) return <LoadingSpinner />
  if (displayItems && displayItems.length === 0) return <Text>Nothing to show</Text>
  return <FlatList
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        onEndReached={fetchItems}
        data={displayItems}
        renderItem={(i) => <ShowItem item={i}/>} />
    
};

export default HomeScreen;

The problem with this is that it flags an error saying The 'fetchItems' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook change on every render..  It suggests To fix this, wrap the definition of 'fetchItems' in its own useCallback() Hook..
So I wrap it in a useCallback() hook:
  const fetchItems = React.useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await client(next, 'GET'); // Just calls axios
    setDisplayItems((items) => items.concat(response.data));
    setNext(response.next);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [next]);

This doesn't run at all unless I add fetchItems(), but at that point it re-renders infinitely.
I can't find anything online that has worked.  The annoying thing is that I remember implementing this for another project a few years ago, and I don't remember it being particularly complicated!

For the main error you mentioned in your question:

Without React.useCallback, on each render (or state update), such as setNext(response.next), a new reference of fetchItems is created. This forces the useEffect to be triggered again, causing another call to fetchItems. This creates a loop of infinite API calls and re-renders.
With React.useCallback, since you've included next (a state variable) in the dependency array, and next is updated within the fetchItems function, when next is updated, React.useCallback will return a new reference to fetchItems, and thus useEffect will be triggered again.

Simple Solution: Remove fetchItems from the useEffect dependency array to avoid triggering re-renders unnecessarily.
Best Practices:

Use useRef instead of useState for next: This prevents unnecessary re-renders, as useRef updates without triggering a re-render, unlike useState.
onEndReached should only be called if there is no API call (data fetching) in progress: Implement a flag(isLoading) or condition to ensure you don't trigger additional fetches while one is already happening.
Use keyExtractor: Always ensure a stable and unique key for each list item to help React optimize rendering efficiently.

Here is the sample solution:


import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {FlatList} from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [displayItems, setDisplayItems] = useState<Item[] | null>(null);

  const nextRef = useRef(BASE_URL);

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await client(nextRef.current, 'GET'); // Just calls axios
    setDisplayItems((items) => items.concat(response.data));
    nextRef.current = response.next;
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  const onEndReached = () => {
    if (!isLoading) {
      fetchItems()
    }
  }

  const listEmptyComponent = () => {
    if (!isLoading && displayItems?.length === 0) {
      return (
        <Text>Nothing to show</Text>
      )
    }
  }

  const renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return <ShowItem item={item}/>
  }

  const listFooterComponent = () => {
    if (isLoading && displayItems?.length > 0) {
      return <LoadingSpinner/>
    }
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={displayItems}
      onEndReached={onEndReached}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      ListFooterComponent={listFooterComponent}
      ListEmptyComponent={listEmptyComponent}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    />
  )

};

export default HomeScreen;




Thank you - that's very helpful.  I'll try it out.  I'm getting VSCode errors if I remove fetchItems from the dependency array for the useEffect - can I just ignore those?

TBH, usually I ignore or suppress this Eslint error. But suppose you do not want to ignore it. In that case, you can use useCallback with an empty array since there is no state variable in fetchItems, and provide fetchItems dependency in useEffect.
to ignore use; // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

glad to help! xD

The comment on your useEffect suggest that the purpose of that effect is to fetch data on the initial render; so you need to add a conditional to that effect to ensure it does that:
// Get items on first loading screen
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(displayItems == null) fetchItems();
  }, [fetchItems,displayItems]);

Doing it this way the useEffect is called when fetchItems or displayItems changes, but only calls fetchItems if displayItems is null (its initial state). I dont think its necessary to wrap fetchItems with useCallback, but this effect should work whether fetchItems is wrapped or not
